# How do I get rid of the comments dropdown in the WordPress dashboard?

Tags: wordpress

The code below removes everything I want except for the comments dropdown.

[image]

That pesky little icon just won't go away. Is there another method?

```
// Remove Admin bar links
function remove_admin_bar_links() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wp-logo');          // Remove the Wordpress logo
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('about');            // Remove the about Wordpress link
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wporg');            // Remove the Wordpress.org link
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('documentation');    // Remove the Wordpress documentation link
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('support-forums');   // Remove the support forums link
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('feedback');         // Remove the feedback link
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('comments');         // Remove the comments link
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-content');      // Remove the content link
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_admin_bar_links' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
function remove_toolbar_node(\WP_Admin_Bar $wp_admin_bar) {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node('comments');
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'remove_toolbar_node', 999);
```

Note that you can use `$wp_admin_bar->get_nodes()` to get available nodes.

Comment: That code still doesn't get rid of the icon.

Comment: Where is the icon you talk about? My code is to remove the comment logo from the admin top bar, as I thought it was the one in your capture.

Comment: Your code gets rid of the comments link. But there is a separate comments icon that doesn't go away unless you add `$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('notes');`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out I have to add: `$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('notes');`

That gets rid of the comments icon.